# Firebase query placing current logged in user first regardless of actual rank until page refresh

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue where I want to display the top users in a leaderboard by an integer value called "ranking", to query this I use `fetchUsers` called in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
func fetchUsers() {
        userModel.removeAll()
        let queryRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "ranking").queryLimited(toLast: 49)
        queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
                let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
                print(user.username)
                print(user.ranking)
                self.userModel.append(user)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.leaderboardTableView.reloadData()
            })
        })
    }
```

So if I have a database with these values and I am logged in as user1:

```
users {
    user1: 
        ranking: 9999874
    user2:
        ranking: 9999752
    user3:
        ranking: 9999999
}
```

I see this printed out in my console (I added a print statement in the query) which is not correct

```
user1
9999874 <<<< this is not the smallest number!
user2
9999752
user3
9999999
```

but if I go back and click through to the leaderboard again, it reloads and shows:

```
user2
9999752
user1
9999874
user3
9999999
```

Correct!

BUT WHY. Here's my tableView code for display:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leaderboardTableCell", for: indexPath) as! LeaderboardTableCell
        if userModel.count > indexPath.row {
            if let profileImageURL = userModel[indexPath.row].photoURL {
                //photo options removed for brevity
                Nuke.loadImage(
                    with: ImageRequest(url: url).processed(with: _ProgressiveBlurImageProcessor()),
                    options: options,
                    into: cell.userImage
                )
            }
        }
        cell.userName.text = userModel[indexPath.row].username
        cell.watchTime.text = "\(String(describing: userModel[indexPath.row].watchTime!))"
        cell.ranking.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
```

And a gif example showing this problem.

CASE: Logged in as appledev I go: profileVC -> LeaderboardVC -> Observe wrong rankings -> go back to profileVC -> open up LeaderboardVC again and it works magically.

Something odd is that this works perfectly on my homeVC and if the query is limited to 10.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Does it fix itself if you go to Leaderboard the first time and scroll tableView all the way down so that the top cells are not visible, and then scroll back to top? This will force tableView reload.

Comment: Actually no, reloading tableView isn't the issue. Can you replace 'observe' with 'observeSingleEvent' and see if it resolves the issue? You will have to change eventType to .value and your logic slightly to handle the snapshot as a list instead of single value.

Comment: @MichaelVoline yea just checked, you can see the images reload because they go off the page, but order stays the same.